# If array includes 2 objects which are the same, then mutate the 2nd (or 3rd, 4th) object's values

Tags: javascript, object

So I have a empty array where I am pushing objects into it.

```
{
      "id": 702361206839,
      "title": "Misanthropy Club Tee",
      "handle": "misanthropy-club-tee",
      "body_html": "<div></div>",
      "published_at": "2018-06-25T21:41:55+01:00",
      "created_at": "2018-06-25T21:41:55+01:00",
      "updated_at": "2018-09-17T14:24:50+01:00",
      "vendor": "J.Parré",
      "product_type": "",
      "tags": [
        "T-Shirts"
      ]
}
```

If I push this same object into the array, I want to be able to mutate the ID key so the value is `702361206839-2`, If I add another then `702361206839-3` and so on. The first object I push into the array stays the same though.

Thank you

Comment: When you say "this same object", do you mean any object with the same `id` value, or literally the same *instance*.

Comment: You can maintain a map with the `id` as key and `count` as value. Whenever pushing new object just check the key in the map, if it exists, change the object `id` to new `id-count` value.

Comment: @nnnnnn same `id` value. In my case the same `id` value will have the same _instance_

Comment: @abhishekkannojia thanks for sharing your thought process, do you think you can provide me with some code?

Answer (score 1):

Just maintain a map of `id` which have been pushed to array with key as the `id` being pushed and value is the count of objects pushed already.

```
var map = {};
var arr = [];
```

Now, let's assume the object you are pushing is `obj`

```
var obj = {
      "id": 702361206839,
      "title": "Misanthropy Club Tee",
      "handle": "misanthropy-club-tee",
      "body_html": "<div></div>",
      "published_at": "2018-06-25T21:41:55+01:00",
      "created_at": "2018-06-25T21:41:55+01:00",
      "updated_at": "2018-09-17T14:24:50+01:00",
      "vendor": "J.Parré",
      "product_type": "",
      "tags": [
        "T-Shirts"
      ]
};
```

Before each push check if it exists in map, if it does, change the object `id` to your desired format.

```
var id = obj.id;
if(map[obj.id]) {
    obj.id = obj.id + '-' + map[obj.id];
} else {
    map[obj.id] = 1;
}

arr.push(obj);
map[id] += 1;
```

Comment: @RamanPlaha To keep the track of the objects which have been pushed to the array. This is more efficient otherwise for every push you would've to traverse the whole array looking for the object with same `id`.